# How to resolve error loading new app electron version - Azure?

Tags: azure-devops, electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

I have an eletron application that I need updated as soon as a new version is available. I'm using Azure devops as a repository and I've made the artifact available. But when the app starts I get this error:

> [2023-06-09 14:36:44.482] [info]  Hello, log
> [2023-06-09 14:36:54.521] [info]  We are checking for updates and notifying user...
> [2023-06-09 14:36:54.524] [info]  Checking for update
> [2023-06-09 14:36:54.527] [info]  Checking for update...
> [2023-06-09 14:36:54.542] [info]  Generated new staging user ID: 94b49447-3ed5-550f-95b2-58d96fb7f15b
> [2023-06-09 14:36:54.787] [error] Error: Error: Cannot parse update info from latest.yml in the latest release artifacts (https://dev.azure.com/my-feed/electron-update/_apis/build/builds/51/artifacts/latest.yml?artifactName=drop&api-version=7.0): YAMLException: end of the stream or a document separator is expected (27:7678)

I tried some url found in the microsoft documentation but it didn't solve

Doubt: Am I using the correct url? Does anyone have an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When your build completed, along with setup file there is a file called `latest.yml`

You need to upload that file to the production, so the updater can check for latest manifest.